# How to get the --rsync-path option to work with the rsync daemon

Tags: services, rsync

I'm currently writing an auto backup system in python that'll dynamically sync to specific directories on a server depending on what user, machine, and os is currently running.

I'm trying to get the following command to work while creating the user, system, os, and sync directories if they don't already exist.

```
rsync -arvR --password-file=./rsyncdpw --rsync-path="mkdir -p /srv/backupdir/jim/desktop/Linux/sync/ && rsync" ./20160602BU user@server::backup/jim/desktop/Linux/sync/
```

If the directories don't exist, no directories are created and, the command fails with:

> sending incremental file list
>   rsync: mkdir "/jim/desktop/Linux/sync" (in backup) failed: No such file or directory (2)
>   rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(674) [Receiver=3.1.1]

The command works perfectly if the directories already exist. Also I've gotten the --rsync-path option working fine when not connecting to the daemon. The following command correctly creates all the directories and syncs the files as expected.

```
rsync -rvR --rsync-path="mkdir -p /srv/backupdir/jim/desktop/Linux/sync/ && rsync" ./20160602BU jim@filesrv:/srv/backupdir/jim/desktop/Linux/sync/
```

The backup module in rsync.conf for the daemon specifies /srv/backupdir as it's directory, so I've tried making only /jim/desktop/Linux/sync to compliment that, and I've also tried the absolute path. Both approaches fail with the same output.

I've been struggling with it for quite a few days in between coding other parts of the system. I've almost finished the system but I've hit a wall at this part.

Thanks for any help you can offer.